# Javascript ignore commas when typing input

Tags: javascript

Here, I have a simple unit converter. It works fine until you enter a comma into the digits. Please help, I'm a javascript beginner, and I am working on a website for a client.

```
$('#thb').on("keyup", function () {
    $("#usd").val(parseInt($("#thb").val()) / 35 + ' USD');
});

$('#usd').on("keyup", function () {
    $("#thb").val(parseInt($("#usd").val()) * 35 + ' THB');
});
```

Comment: Remove the commas using `str_replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove commas from the strings with string.replace():

```
$('#thb').on("keyup", function () {
    $("#usd").val(parseInt($("#thb").val().replace(/\,/g,'')) / 35 + ' USD');
});

$('#usd').on("keyup", function () {
    $("#thb").val(parseInt($("#usd").val().replace(/\,/g,'')) * 35 + ' THB');
});
```

Comment: You have an extra ")"  on line 7. Thanks for your response. It works finely.

Comment: tnx, extra ")" removed